# Time-sensitive pipe causes ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError

Tags: angular, typescript

In my Angular 12 app I have a component that lists files, and shows how recently they were updated. I format "recency" in the "3 minutes ago" format using a pipe (relevant parts shown here):

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'ago',
  pure: false
})
export class TimeAgoPipe implements PipeTransform, OnDestroy {
  public constructor(private readonly changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef, private readonly ngZone: NgZone) { }
  public transform(value: number | string | Date) {
    [logic to calculate seconds...]
    return `${seconds} seconds ago`;
  }
```

Then in my component I have something roughly like this:

```
<ul *ngFor="let file of files">
  <li>{{file.name}} (updated {{file.updatedDate | ago}})</li>
</ul>
```

This pipe obviously handles minutes, days etc. but it's when the time is really short that I have a problem because the value created by the pipe changes frequently. It's set to impure because it's output is not idempotent - this seems like a valid use case for an impure pipe to me. Occasionally I see a `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` thrown when the check catches the pipe as it's ticking over from 7 seconds to 8 seconds for example.

I understand what `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError` is and how to avoid it in most scenarios where code sitting behind the component is changing bound data, but I haven't been able to find any information about what to do when it is caused by a pipe.

Is there any way to suppress the error from within a pipe or implement the desired behaviour in such a way as not to invoke the error in the first place? (ideally without `ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush` - I really don't want to take responsibility for the change detection strategy of every component that uses this pipe if I can help it).

Comment: Should the pipe update the value every second?

Comment: Now that you say that, it's clear I hadn't given much thought to how often I wanted it to update - but certainly not every second. I think really it should just be on initial rendering or when the underlying source data changes. To that end, what I've done is inject my pipe into the controller and used it to fill in an additional "updateDateAgo" property on the file object. This both fixes the ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError and makes the timing of updates to the value shown on screen more deterministic. In hindsight what I was doing was a bit smelly in the first place.